# How do you view a redis stored lua script (for debugging)?

Tags: ruby, lua, redis

I have an error in a redis script (from the ruby "Qless" gem) that I need to debug:

```
ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.7/lib/redis/client.rb:97:in `call': ERR Error running script (call to f_f7526d197070c9e82c28fad331b4c020585aad20): user_script:33: bad argument #1 to 'decode' (string expected, got boolean) (Redis::CommandError)
```

How do I map `f_f7526d197070c9e82c28fad331b4c020585aad20` back to the code that was defined by this Qless library? Is the best way to manually copy paste each of the (30 or so) LUA scripts in Qless to redis-cli and see which corresponds to the sha? (I'm hoping there's a better way?)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but not trivial.

You can use [AOF](http://redis.io/topics/persistence#append-only-file).

Do a `CONFIG SET appendonly yes`, compress the AOF by [BGREWRITEAOF](http://redis.io/commands/bgrewriteaof), execute your script(s), and look at the contents of the AOF file. Your complete script is in there.

Hope this helps, TW

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding debug info to the `Qless::LuaScript#reload` method (inside the gem, temporarily):

```
def reload()
  @sha = @redis.script(:load, script_contents)
  puts @sha
  puts script_contents
  puts '-----'
  @sha
end
```

This provides the SHA at call-time, so when the error mentioned above is shown, the LUA source code is also visible somewhere up above in the scroll log where the script was defined.